# передача данных между middlewares

Tags: golang

всем привет.

у меня есть несколько мидлваре в проекте, они запускаются одна за другой при запросе определенного урла перед тем как запустить финальный хэндлфанк

Я столкнулся с тем что данные из первоначального запроса, теряются при проходе через мидлварь. например данные заполненных форм.

сейчас, чтобы донести данные первоначального запроса до финального хэндфанка, я в первой мидлвари данные запроса сохраняю и дальше передаю в следующую мидлварь в качестве хедера. есть ли более практичный способ донести данные от первоначального запроса до финального хэндлфанка?
спасибо.

Comment: Для этого обычно используют контекст, к примеру, в [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас http/net, то примерно так:

Первый посредник (выполняется первым)

```
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx,"YOU_KEY", "YOU_VALUE")
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
}
```

Второй посредник (выполняется вторым)

```
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    v := r.Context().Value("YOU_KEY")
    // some logic
}
```

Comment: А является ли использование хэдеров вместо контекста хорошей идеей?

Comment: нет, если данные для передачи между посредниками только (там может лежать объект какой-то, не только скаляры (у меня например юзер лежит после посредника аутентификации), могут быть чувствительные данные)

Comment: А, можно и обьекты в конктесте передавать? Неплохо)) Не хватало этого когда передавал пользователя

Comment: Маршалил обьект в json, ставил хэдер со строкой этого json, на следующем мидлвари или в хэнлфанке получал хэдер, преобразовывал в []byte, делал анмаршалинг. Во как контекст жизнь упрощает